# how to wait for child components rendered

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

how do I wait till child components loaded so I can check toMatchSnapshot whole Parent component?

```
<MyComponent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</MyComponent>
```

//unit test

```
it('test parent component', () => {
    let mycomponent = render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(mycomponent.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

render renders without child components. Children are loaded in e.g. 5 sec.. Is there a way to do it without mocking Children? I want them to be loaded themself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`findBy*` queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) to wait for a certain element to be present in the DOM.

For instance, if one of the children has an element with `'Some string'` text:

```js
it('test parent component', async () => {
    let mycomponent = render(<MyComponent />)
    await screen.findByText('Some string')
    expect(mycomponent.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Note that `findBy*` queries (like `waitFor`) have a default 1000ms timeout, which can be increased by passing a `timeout` value in the `options` object as last parameter.